# PDB files to angles to again converting in PDB format

Tags: java, python, c++, performance, biopython

I have PDB file then i am converting it in file which gives dihedral angles.But now i had modified some angles and need to convert these modified angles again to a new pdb file.Is there any library for it?

I had converted pdb to angles file using prody , biopython library.

Answer (score 0):

not sure about your question, about changing format from cartesian coordinates to internal ones using Biopython Python Library ;

with input file `test_A.pdb` peptide made with PyMOL `fab 'AGW'` :

```
HEADER    peptide made with pymol fab 'AGW'                   16-NOV-23   
TITLE     AGW PEPTIDE NO PROPER FOLDING
ATOM      1  N   ALA A   1      -0.677  -1.230  -0.491  1.00  0.00           N  
ATOM      2  CA  ALA A   1      -0.001   0.064  -0.491  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM      3  C   ALA A   1       1.499  -0.110  -0.491  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM      4  O   ALA A   1       2.030  -1.227  -0.502  1.00  0.00           O  
ATOM      5  CB  ALA A   1      -0.509   0.856   0.727  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM      6  H   ALA A   1      -0.131  -2.162  -0.491  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM      7  HA  ALA A   1      -0.269   0.603  -1.418  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM      8 1HB  ALA A   1      -1.605   1.006   0.691  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM      9 2HB  ALA A   1      -0.285   0.342   1.681  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     10 3HB  ALA A   1      -0.053   1.861   0.784  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     11  N   GLY A   2       2.250   0.939  -0.479  1.00  0.00           N  
ATOM     12  CA  GLY A   2       3.700   0.771  -0.479  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     13  C   GLY A   2       4.400   2.108  -0.463  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     14  O   GLY A   2       3.775   3.173  -0.453  1.00  0.00           O  
ATOM     15  H   GLY A   2       1.841   1.862  -0.470  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     16 3HA  GLY A   2       3.972   0.246  -1.347  0.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     17  HA  GLY A   2       3.998   0.221   0.434  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     18  N   TRP A   3       5.689   2.140  -0.462  1.00  0.00           N  
ATOM     19  CA  TRP A   3       6.366   3.433  -0.447  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     20  C   TRP A   3       7.866   3.260  -0.448  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     21  O   TRP A   3       8.393   2.149  -0.460  1.00  0.00           O  
ATOM     22  CB  TRP A   3       5.929   4.221   0.819  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     23  CG  TRP A   3       4.453   4.629   0.843  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     24  CD1 TRP A   3       3.416   3.929   1.494  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     25  CD2 TRP A   3       3.843   5.674   0.179  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     26  CE2 TRP A   3       2.452   5.600   0.436  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     27  CE3 TRP A   3       4.369   6.688  -0.662  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     28  NE1 TRP A   3       2.161   4.520   1.256  1.00  0.00           N  
ATOM     29  CZ2 TRP A   3       1.576   6.547  -0.138  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     30  CZ3 TRP A   3       3.485   7.617  -1.212  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     31  CH2 TRP A   3       2.109   7.550  -0.952  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     32  H   TRP A   3       6.223   1.283  -0.470  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     33  HA  TRP A   3       6.094   3.995  -1.361  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     34 2HB  TRP A   3       6.531   5.144   0.923  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     35 3HB  TRP A   3       6.163   3.638   1.731  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     36 1HD  TRP A   3       3.567   3.021   2.064  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     37 1HE  TRP A   3       1.238   4.200   1.570  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     38 3HE  TRP A   3       5.428   6.743  -0.874  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     39 2HZ  TRP A   3       0.515   6.495   0.054  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     40 3HZ  TRP A   3       3.870   8.400  -1.849  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     41 2HH  TRP A   3       1.450   8.285  -1.388  1.00  0.00           H  
TER   
END
```

and code stealed from [Bio.PDB.internal_coords module](https://biopython.org/docs/latest/api/Bio.PDB.internal_coords.html) :

```
"""
stealing from  https://biopython.org/docs/dev/api/Bio.PDB.internal_coords.html

"""

import Bio

import Bio
print('########## Biopython  VERSION ##########################################')
print('\n                BIOPYTHON_VERSION : ', Bio.__version__)
print('\n########################################################################\n\n')


from Bio.PDB.PDBParser import PDBParser
from Bio.PDB.internal_coords import *
from Bio.PDB.PICIO import write_PIC, read_PIC
from Bio.PDB.ic_rebuild import structure_rebuild_test

from Bio.PDB.PDBIO import PDBIO



IC_Residue.accept_atoms = IC_Residue.accept_mainchain + ('H',) ## * can break buildtest sometimes , see https://biopython.org/docs/latest/api/Bio.PDB.internal_coords.html#Bio.PDB.internal_coords.IC_Residue

print('\nIC_Residue.accept_atoms : ' , IC_Residue.accept_atoms)

print(IC_Chain.MaxPeptideBond)

IC_Chain.MaxPeptideBond = 0.1 ## writes different .pic files but when re-covering them to .pdb file there are no changes
                              ## try changing to 1.4
                              ## .pic file should have different chain name for each aa , but doesnt
 
print(IC_Chain.MaxPeptideBond)

# load a structure as normal, get first chain

parser = PDBParser(QUIET = True)

myProtein = parser.get_structure("test", "test_A.pdb") # test wrong dihedral angles  ?? peptide made with pymol fab 'AGW'

myProtein = myProtein[0]['A']

myProtein.atom_to_internal_coordinates(verbose=True)

resultDict = structure_rebuild_test(myProtein) 

print("ASSERTION : \  resultDict['pass'] == True ---->  " ,  resultDict['pass'] == True)  # --> False because of wrong starting tripeptide dihedrals

# Cant use :  assert resultDict['pass'] == True  that would break the code


# write chain as 'protein internal coordinates' (.pic) file
write_PIC(myProtein, "myProtein__.pic")


# read .pic file
#reading from .pic file doesnt neeed to use .atom_to_internal_coordinates(verbose=True)
myProtein2 = read_PIC("myProtein__.pic")

print('\nmyProtein2 : ' , myProtein2 , type(myProtein2))

for i in myProtein2[0]['A'] :
    
    print(i)
    
    
print(myProtein2[0]['A'].internal_coord.dihedra)

"""

modify here your angles


Using as explained in the below (after code , posted links) :

dictionary_IC : Dict[Tuple[PDB.internal_coords.AtomKey, 
                       PDB.internal_coords.AtomKey,
                       PDB.internal_coords.AtomKey,
                       PDB.internal_coords.AtomKey],
                 PDB.internal_coords.Dihedron] = myProtein2[0]['A'].internal_coord.dihedra 


"""
    
print('\n\n')
myProtein3 = read_PIC('myProtein__.pic', verbose = True , quick = False , defaults = False)

myProtein3.internal_to_atom_coordinates(verbose = True)

io = PDBIO()

io.set_structure(myProtein3)

io.save('protein_from_pic.pdb')
```

How to acces dihedral angles :

[Read PDB file, extract dihedral angles, modify dihedral angles, reconstruct Cartesian coordinates, and write PDB file](https://biopython.org/docs/dev/api/Bio.PDB.internal_coords.html#Bio.PDB.internal_coords.IC_Chain) or

[class Bio.PDB.internal_coords.IC_Chain(parent: Chain, verbose: bool = False)](https://biopython.org/docs/dev/api/Bio.PDB.internal_coords.html#Bio.PDB.internal_coords.IC_Chain)

you get the internal coordinates `protein_from_pic.pdb` file :

```
('test', 0, 'A', (' ', 1, ' ')) ALA
ATOM      1  N   ALA A   1      -0.67700  -1.23000  -0.49100  1.000  0.00           N
ATOM      2  CA  ALA A   1      -0.00100   0.06400  -0.49100  1.000  0.00           C
ATOM      3  C   ALA A   1       1.49900  -0.11000  -0.49100  1.000  0.00           C
 A 1_A_N:1_A_CA:1_A_C   1.4599356281937 110.9663284912222   1.5100582309311
 A 1_A_N:1_A_CA:1_A_CB   1.4599356281937 107.6539249931262   1.5391075321658
 A 1_A_CA:1_A_C:1_A_O   1.5100582309311 122.0408231232925   1.2368391228534
 A 1_A_CB:1_A_CA:1_A_C   1.5391075321658 112.7777186574113   1.5100582309311
 A 1_A_H:1_A_N:1_A_CA   1.0801573228592 122.0535853278094   1.4599356281937
 A 1_A_N:1_A_CA:1_A_C:1_A_O   0.6011491153007
 A 1_A_C:1_A_CA:1_A_N:1_A_H  -0.0000000000000
 A 1_A_O:1_A_C:1_A_CA:1_A_CB 121.4745127527640
BFAC: 1_A_N   0.00 1_A_CA   0.00 1_A_C   0.00 1_A_O   0.00 1_A_1HB   0.00
BFAC: 1_A_2HB   0.00 1_A_3HB   0.00 1_A_CB   0.00 1_A_H   0.00 1_A_HA   0.00
('test', 0, 'A', (' ', 2, ' ')) GLY
ATOM     11  N   GLY A   2       2.25000   0.93900  -0.47900  1.000  0.00           N
ATOM     12  CA  GLY A   2       3.70000   0.77100  -0.47900  1.000  0.00           C
ATOM     13  C   GLY A   2       4.40000   2.10800  -0.46300  1.000  0.00           C
 A 2_G_N:2_G_CA:2_G_C   1.4597000145629 111.0245898953170   1.5092465338681
 A 2_G_CA:2_G_C:2_G_O   1.5092465338681 121.9611199529751   1.2348887082198
 A 2_G_H:2_G_N:2_G_CA   1.0095994213317 120.5067023787684   1.4597000145629
 A 2_G_N:2_G_CA:2_G_C:2_G_O  -0.0655685928394
 A 2_G_C:2_G_CA:2_G_N:2_G_H   0.0579117354546
BFAC: 2_G_N   0.00 2_G_CA   0.00 2_G_C   0.00 2_G_O   0.00 2_G_3HA_0.0   0.00
BFAC: 2_G_H   0.00 2_G_HA   0.00
('test', 0, 'A', (' ', 3, ' ')) TRP
ATOM     18  N   TRP A   3       5.68900   2.14000  -0.46200  1.000  0.00           N
ATOM     19  CA  TRP A   3       6.36600   3.43300  -0.44700  1.000  0.00           C
ATOM     20  C   TRP A   3       7.86600   3.26000  -0.44800  1.000  0.00           C
 A 3_W_N:3_W_CA:3_W_C   1.4595900171125 111.0554053056338   1.5099437187163
 A 3_W_N:3_W_CA:3_W_CB   1.4595900171125 109.0964244104475   1.5539206591801
 A 3_W_CA:3_W_C:3_W_O   1.5099437187163 121.9549562239499   1.2297128041268
 A 3_W_CA:3_W_CB:3_W_CG   1.5539206591801 114.7641940305710   1.5315402370701
 A 3_W_CB:3_W_CA:3_W_C   1.5539206591801 109.7558500446390   1.5099437187163
 A 3_W_CB:3_W_CG:3_W_CD1   1.5315402370701 125.7050933265825   1.4103796384618
 A 3_W_CB:3_W_CG:3_W_CD2   1.5315402370701 128.3225156449208   1.3802247324184
 A 3_W_CG:3_W_CD1:3_W_NE1   1.4103796384618 111.6636250373605   1.4074621641653
 A 3_W_CG:3_W_CD2:3_W_CE2   1.3802247324184 107.8886960838606   1.4164766375332
 A 3_W_CG:3_W_CD2:3_W_CE3   1.3802247324184 131.4953244410757   1.4185040982489
 A 3_W_CD2:3_W_CE2:3_W_CZ2   1.4164766375332 120.0300532767627   1.4119705760319
 A 3_W_CE2:3_W_CZ2:3_W_CH2   1.4119705760319 118.7879027230004   1.3973884762513
 A 3_W_CZ2:3_W_CH2:3_W_CZ3   1.3973884762513 121.1110777259555   1.4019503499843
 A 3_W_H:3_W_N:3_W_CA   1.0097866641569 120.4393494994194   1.4595900171125
 A 3_W_N:3_W_CA:3_W_C:3_W_O  -0.0102553301826
 A 3_W_N:3_W_CA:3_W_CB:3_W_CG -66.0812643271944
 A 3_W_CA:3_W_CB:3_W_CG:3_W_CD1  96.7505848410883
 A 3_W_CA:3_W_CB:3_W_CG:3_W_CD2 -78.3824577321078
 A 3_W_C:3_W_CA:3_W_N:3_W_H   0.0868587990605
 A 3_W_O:3_W_C:3_W_CA:3_W_CB 120.7037597691334
 A 3_W_CB:3_W_CG:3_W_CD1:3_W_NE1 -176.3052251151737
 A 3_W_CB:3_W_CG:3_W_CD2:3_W_CE2 176.0783225890677
 A 3_W_CB:3_W_CG:3_W_CD2:3_W_CE3  -2.4869103253617
 A 3_W_CG:3_W_CD2:3_W_CE2:3_W_CZ2 -179.2603454806913
 A 3_W_CD2:3_W_CE2:3_W_CZ2:3_W_CH2  -0.2347405513300
 A 3_W_CE2:3_W_CZ2:3_W_CH2:3_W_CZ3   0.6321110551692
BFAC: 3_W_N   0.00 3_W_CA   0.00 3_W_C   0.00 3_W_O   0.00 3_W_1HD   0.00
BFAC: 3_W_1HE   0.00 3_W_2HB   0.00 3_W_2HH   0.00 3_W_2HZ   0.00 3_W_3HB   0.00
BFAC: 3_W_3HE   0.00 3_W_3HZ   0.00 3_W_CB   0.00 3_W_CD1   0.00 3_W_CD2   0.00
BFAC: 3_W_CE2   0.00 3_W_CE3   0.00 3_W_CG   0.00 3_W_CH2   0.00 3_W_CZ2   0.00
BFAC: 3_W_CZ3   0.00 3_W_H   0.00 3_W_HA   0.00 3_W_NE1   0.00
```

and then again a .pdb file , in this case second file is missing the side-chains H because of the `IC_Residue.accept_atoms = IC_Residue.accept_mainchain + ('H',)` ,

pdbs compared :

[image]

pdb compared in pymol , one structure is translated a little bit by hand :

[image]

**ADDENDUM**

On an another note without dealing with `.pic` files , using same input above , you could do :

```
import Bio

print('########## Biopython  VERSION ##########################################')
print('\n                BIOPYTHON_VERSION : ', Bio.__version__)
print('\n########################################################################\n\n')


from Bio.PDB.PDBParser import PDBParser
from Bio.PDB.internal_coords import *

from Bio.PDB.PDBIO import PDBIO



IC_Residue.accept_atoms = IC_Residue.accept_mainchain + ('H',) ## * can break buildtest sometimes , see https://biopython.org/docs/latest/api/Bio.PDB.internal_coords.html#Bio.PDB.internal_coords.IC_Residue

print('\nIC_Residue.accept_atoms : ' , IC_Residue.accept_atoms)

print(IC_Chain.MaxPeptideBond)

# IC_Chain.MaxPeptideBond = 0.1 ## writes different .pic files but when re-covering them to .pdb file there are no changes
                              ## try changing to 1.4
                              ## .pic file should have different chain name for each aa , but doesnt
                              
IC_Chain.MaxPeptideBond = 1.4 ### default ,  with 0.1 I have no peptide bond !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!                              
                            
 
print(IC_Chain.MaxPeptideBond)


parser = PDBParser(QUIET = True)

myProtein = parser.get_structure("test", "test_A.pdb") # test wrong dihedral angles  ?? peptide made with pymol fab 'AGW'

myChain = myProtein[0]['A']

myChain.atom_to_internal_coordinates(verbose=True)

myChain.internal_to_atom_coordinates(verbose=True)



for i in myChain.get_residues() :
    
    print('\n',i)
    
    print(i.internal_coord , type(i.internal_coord))
    
    
    
    for ang in ["psi", "phi" , "omg" , "chi1" , "chi2" , "chi3" , "chi4" , "chi5"] :
        
    
    # for ang in ["N:CA:C:1N", "-1C:N:CA:C" , "-1CA:-1C:N:CA" ] :  # psi , phi , omega
    
    ## see https://biopython.org/docs/dev/api/Bio.PDB.internal_coords.html#Bio.PDB.internal_coords.IC_Residue
        

    
        ric = i.internal_coord.get_angle(ang)
    
        if ric != None :
    
            print('\n', ang, ' in ', i ,'  : ',ric , type(ric))
            
            if ang == 'chi1' :
                
                
                change = i.internal_coord.set_angle(ang , ric - 47.0)
                
                changed = i.internal_coord.get_angle(ang)
                
                print('\n', ang, ' CHANGED !!!!! in ', i ,'  : ',changed , type(changed))
                
            else :
                
                pass
            
        else :
            
            
            print('\n', ang ,'  is not present in ' , i)
    

myChain.internal_to_atom_coordinates(verbose=True)
 
io = PDBIO()

io.set_structure(myChain)

io.save('protein_modified_angles.pdb')
```

Output :

```
.....
 <Residue ALA het=  resseq=1 icode= >
('test', 0, 'A', (' ', 1, ' ')) <class 'Bio.PDB.internal_coords.IC_Residue'>

 psi  in  <Residue ALA het=  resseq=1 icode= >   :  -179.39078992201667 <class 'numpy.float64'>

 phi   is not present in  <Residue ALA het=  resseq=1 icode= >

 omg   is not present in  <Residue ALA het=  resseq=1 icode= >

 chi1   is not present in  <Residue ALA het=  resseq=1 icode= >

 chi2   is not present in  <Residue ALA het=  resseq=1 icode= >

 chi3   is not present in  <Residue ALA het=  resseq=1 icode= >

 chi4   is not present in  <Residue ALA het=  resseq=1 icode= >

 chi5   is not present in  <Residue ALA het=  resseq=1 icode= >

 <Residue GLY het=  resseq=2 icode= >
('test', 0, 'A', (' ', 2, ' ')) <class 'Bio.PDB.internal_coords.IC_Residue'>

 psi  in  <Residue GLY het=  resseq=2 icode= >   :  -179.94682725665908 <class 'numpy.float64'>

 phi  in  <Residue GLY het=  resseq=2 icode= >   :  -179.9585097414913 <class 'numpy.float64'>

 omg  in  <Residue GLY het=  resseq=2 icode= >   :  -179.99990519647523 <class 'numpy.float64'>

 chi1   is not present in  <Residue GLY het=  resseq=2 icode= >

 chi2   is not present in  <Residue GLY het=  resseq=2 icode= >

 chi3   is not present in  <Residue GLY het=  resseq=2 icode= >

 chi4   is not present in  <Residue GLY het=  resseq=2 icode= >

 chi5   is not present in  <Residue GLY het=  resseq=2 icode= >

 <Residue TRP het=  resseq=3 icode= >
('test', 0, 'A', (' ', 3, ' ')) <class 'Bio.PDB.internal_coords.IC_Residue'>

 psi   is not present in  <Residue TRP het=  resseq=3 icode= >

 phi  in  <Residue TRP het=  resseq=3 icode= >   :  179.99102008513498 <class 'numpy.float64'>

 omg  in  <Residue TRP het=  resseq=3 icode= >   :  179.97874022131657 <class 'numpy.float64'>

 chi1  in  <Residue TRP het=  resseq=3 icode= >   :  -66.08126432719439 <class 'numpy.float64'>

 chi1  CHANGED !!!!! in  <Residue TRP het=  resseq=3 icode= >   :  -113.08126432719439 <class 'numpy.float64'>

 chi2  in  <Residue TRP het=  resseq=3 icode= >   :  96.75058484108833 <class 'numpy.float64'>

 chi3   is not present in  <Residue TRP het=  resseq=3 icode= >

 chi4   is not present in  <Residue TRP het=  resseq=3 icode= >

 chi5   is not present in  <Residue TRP het=  resseq=3 icode= >
test A coordinates for 10 dihedra updated in 6 iterations
```

with resulting `protein_modified_angles.pdb` in purple versus original `test_A.pdb` in cyan displayed in PyMOL :

[image]